# How to the display the next step for user who has installed my Google add-on?

Tags: installation, add-on

I developed a Google sheet add-on which works on a template. After user has installed my add-on, I would like to display next step for user to copy the template as in the photo below:

[image: photo]

I looked up onInstall and Deployment but could not find way to do it.

Please advise how to insert the step.